# Populating a group of Check Boxes with True and False

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

The Following code will give me a list of True and False down the page, once in a table.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Runs.Count; i++)
{ 
    @Model.Runs[i].RunGroomed
}
```

And this will give me a list of True and False with a bunch of un-checked Check Boxes along side.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Runs.Count; i++)
{ 
    @Model.Runs[i].RunGroomed
    @Html.CheckBox("Model.Runs[i].RunGroomed")
}
```

How can I put the values of the True and False into the Check Boxes?

Comment: Use the second overload of the `@Html.CheckBox(string name, bool isChecked)` method

Comment: Not sure whet that means in regard to my question?

Comment: Pass the value of the property (true or false) as the second parameter e.g. '@Html.CheckBox("Model.Runs[i].RunGroomed", Model.Runs[i].RunGroomed)`

Comment: Thanks again Stephen, I added some comments below!

Answer (score 0):

That is the answer, it was the first thing I tried but it gave an error, we had just missed out one thing and you put me on the right track, the (bool)

```
@Html.CheckBox("Model.Runs[i].RunGroomed", (bool)Model.Runs[i].RunGroomed)
```

It's working now.

**Edit**

I would like to mark myself as the answer but Stephen has done all the work so I can't?

His second approach has worked out better for me and has taught me a little more about MVC at the same time. I didn't realize I could Strongly Type my own home made View Models. so I thought I should share.

The model I was using in my View looked like this:

```
@using mysite.Models
```

Therefore not strongly typed, so I was unable to use CheckBoxFor() and resulted to CheckBox()

```
@model mysite.Models.RunReport
```

RunReport is my View Model

I'm now able to use the strongly typed,

```
@foreach(var item in Model.Runs) 
{ 
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(i => item.RunGroomed) 
}
```